# Как соединить точки чтобы образовалась сеть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, numpy

Стоит задача соединить точки, но как бы я не пытался, ничего не выходит, либо точки, либо пустой график.

Как  можно соединить точки, так чтобы образовалась сеть?

И вопрос не в тему, почему на втором графике не задается сетка? Задается только если явно в цикле писать.

[image: График]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def polar(n,m,L=(0,0),scale=1):
    #n - кол-во кругов, m - кол-во точек, L - центр, scale - масштаб
    dr=1/n#Расстояние
    df=(2*np.pi)/m#Поворот
    for i in range(n+1):
        for k in range(m+1):
            z=i*dr*np.cos(k*df)+1j*i*dr*np.sin(k*df)
            w=(z-1)**2
            plt.subplot(122)
            plt.plot(w.real*scale,w.imag*scale,'r.')
            circle=i*dr*np.cos(k*df)+1j*i*dr*np.sin(k*df)
            plt.subplot(121)
            plt.plot(circle.real*scale,circle.imag*scale,'r.')
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
    plt.xlabel('Real')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


polar(25,25)
```

Comment: Вы хотите соединить точки таким образом, чтобы на первом графике получились концентрические окружности - я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо большое, возник вопрос, а почему во вложенном цикле не соединяются точки в сетку?

Comment: Потому что во вложенном цикле вы на каждом шаге рисуете только одну точку (на каждом графике), которую не с чем соединять. `plot()` умеет соединять точки если их больше одной...

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо еще раз, за оперативность и разъяснение  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если задача - соединить точки, принадлежащие концентрическим окружностям, то можно так сделать:

```
def polar(n,m,L=(0,0),scale=1):
    #n - кол-во кругов, m - кол-во точек, L - центр, scale - масштаб
    dr=1/n#Расстояние
    df=(2*np.pi)/m#Поворот

    ax1 = plt.subplot(122)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(121)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax2.grid(True)

    k = np.arange(m+1)

    for i in range(n+1):
        z=i*dr*np.cos(k*df)+1j*i*dr*np.sin(k*df)
        w=(z-1)**2
        ax1.plot(w.real*scale,w.imag*scale,'.r-')
        circle=i*dr*np.cos(k*df)+1j*i*dr*np.sin(k*df)
        ax2.plot(circle.real*scale,circle.imag*scale,'.r-')

    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.ylabel('Imaginary')
    plt.xlabel('Real')
    plt.show()

polar(25, 25)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS я избавился от внутреннего цикла по двум причинам:

- для удобства соединения точек одной окружности
- чтобы быстрее считать координаты "**векторизованными**" NumPy методами